# Elasticsearch match multiple fields with AND operator not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am trying to fetch documents from elasticsearch with multiple fields using AND operator

for the below query am expecting the following results

`AB-7000-8002-W`

But am getting this error message `Unrecognized token 'get': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@40d2a7e8; line: 1, column: 5]`

```
 get my_index12/_search {
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "code": {
                         "query": "AB-5000-6002-AK",
                         "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "locale": {
                         "query": "en_US",
                         "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
 }
```

Please find my index documents below

```
 {
        "_index": "my_index12",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "code": "AB-7000-8002-W",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index12",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "code": "AB-7000-8002-W",
          "locale": "en_EU"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index12",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "code": "sG66tsdF",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index12",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "code": "AB-7000-6002-WK",
          "locale": "en_EU"
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just move curly brace in the line `get my_index12/_search {` to the next line.
It should work.

In order to get results which satisfy both the conditions, you have to use `must` clause instead of `should`. "AND" operator in `match` query is not meant for the use case you want to achieve. Use below query.

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "code": {
          "query": "TE-7000-8002-W",
          "operator": "and"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "locale": {
          "query": "en_US",
          "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, its working., but its bring all the records which containing `en_US`, actually it should compare with both the fields `code & locale` with AND operator

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for AND like query on multiple fields should work . Below will search for code as "TE-7000-8002-W" and locale as en_US only

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                       "code": "TE-7000-8002-W"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                       "locale": "en_US"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```